# ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { (has extras) }

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activity, let's call it `MainActivity` which has an `SomeAdapter`. 
In the adapter's code I have

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OptionViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Option o = values.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(o.getOption());
    holder.foreGround.setBackgroundColor(o.getOptionLayout().getBackGroundColor());

    holder.editOptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("option",o);
            context.startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });
}
```

When actually clicking the editOptionButton, I get the following stack trace

> Process: com.company.app, PID: 20916
>       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { (has extras) }
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2007)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
>           at com.company.app.adapters.OptionsAdapter$1.onClick(OptionsAdapter.java:86)

the context that calls `startActivityForResult` is the `MainActivity` and is not null and alive (visible) at the time of calling because the adapter runs in it.

Therefor, I have no idea why this error pops up nor what I could do about it. Do any of you may know why or have experienced it before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include the Activity name like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("option",o);
 context.startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Comment: I really cannot believe myself I looked over the Intent parameters while the rest of my app had the right code. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

**First**

you are initlizing the intent in wrong way, you need init it as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
```

**Second**

If the **result** do not return to your MainActivity then you need to cast the context to activity before starting the second activity as:

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that intent doesn't know where to go. So give the context and the activity name where u want to go.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("Key",value);
 startActvity(intent);
```